# Path range index facet search not working in Marklogic 9

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-9

Hi I am using search API to develop search functionality i have defined the constraint on the node "ti" and configure the path range index in the database. when i try to search using constraint then it shows zero result, but the same thing working in the Marklogic 8, is there any thing missing in the configuration. please suggest. below is the code.

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";

import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search" 
  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $PageLength := 10

let $Start := 1
let $SearchOption := 
    <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
        <return-facets>true</return-facets>
        <term>
            <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
            <term-option>stemmed</term-option>
            <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
            <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
        </term>
        <constraint name="ti">
            <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/" type="xs:string" facet="true">
                <path-index>/bibliog/ti</path-index>
            </range>
        </constraint>
        <additional-query>{cts:collection-query('ID xmls')}</additional-query>
    </options>

return search:search('ti:Indium', $SearchOption, $Start, $PageLength)
```

Comment: What release of MarkLogic 9 are you using, and could you try with the very latest?

Comment: I am using Marklogic version 9.0-7.2. even i have tried the simple query: cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:path-range-query('/bibliog/ti','=','Indium'),'unfiltered') this is also not working.

Comment: XML structure is : <article type="current"><bibliog><ti>Interface sharpening in miscible Ni/Cu multilayers studied by atom probe tomography</ti></bibliog></article>
so i am configuring path range index "/bibliog/ti"  i have tried this one cts:search(fn:doc(),cts:path-range-query('/bibliog/ti','=','Indium'),'unfiltered')  on the Marklogic version 7.0-5.5 but it is not working.

Comment: Shouldn't the path be `bibliog/ti` or `/article/bibliog/ti`?

Comment: Thanks @grtjn it was problem of the XPATH